# flutter FutureBuilder loop snapshot arrays

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting API data and it returns data of 5 arrays like this:

```
print('one: ${jsonResponse['one']}');
print('two: ${jsonResponse['two']}');
print('three: ${jsonResponse['three']}');
print('four: ${jsonResponse['four']}');
print('five: ${jsonResponse['five']}');
```

> Each line is an array of data and all comes from single API URL.

**My question is:** how to divide this arrays in order to show them as separate block in my screen?

`Code`

This is what I have right now:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late Future myCards;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myCards = getHome();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: myCards,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  // require to separate arrays here
                  return Text('Hello!');
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getHome() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://example.com/api/home'),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json'
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<
          String,
          dynamic>;
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('one: ${jsonResponse['one']}'); // returning array of data
        print('two: ${jsonResponse['two']}'); // returning array of data
        print('three: ${jsonResponse['three']}'); // returning array of data
        print('four: ${jsonResponse['four']}'); // returning array of data
        print('five: ${jsonResponse['five']}'); // returning array of data
      }
      return jsonResponse;
    } else {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

> PS: Please feel free to suggest better approach if you have any in
> your mind, I'm open to all solutions.

## Update

I've managed to get my data separately in my screen with code below

```
child: FutureBuilder(
  future: myCards,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          //one
          ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data['one'].length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(snapshot.data['one'][index]['heading']),
                        ],
                      );
                  }
              ),
          //two
          ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data['two'].length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(snapshot.data['two'][index]['name']),
                  ],
                );
              }
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.error}'));
    }
    // By default, show a loading spinner.
    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
),
```

But I'm facing following error:

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#bc93a relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the **scrollDirection** of each list is **vercital** then this should solve the problem.

```
  ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
           physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),                  
           itemCount: snapshot.data['one'].length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(snapshot.data['one'][index]['heading']),
                    ],
                  );
              }
          ),
      //two
      ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data['two'].length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(snapshot.data['two'][index]['name']),
              ],
            );
          }
      ),
```

But if one is **horizontal** you have to give it height.

example-->

```
                 SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child:           ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data['one'].length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(snapshot.data['one'][index]['heading']),
                    ],
                  );
              }
          )),
      //two
      ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data['two'].length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(snapshot.data['two'][index]['name']),
              ],
            );
          }
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have sth like:

```
            child: FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
              future: myCards,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  // Get your map from the snapshot
                  // If possible change "dynamic" to the specific type
                  final Map<String, dynamic> responseMap = snapshot.data!;
                  final List<Widget> children = [];

                  for(final key in responseMap.keys) {
                    // Considering the "dynamic" is a List of Strings
                    final List<String> response = responseMap[key];
                    // Iterate through each response
                    for(final item in response) {
                      // Build the widget for each item
                      children.add(Text(item));
                    } 
                  }
                  // Use a Widget that can display a list of Widgets,
                  // such as ListView, PageView, Column
                  return Column(children:children);

                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            ),
```

Comment: Thank you, would you mind check my update?

Comment: I'd try to change the Column main size to min.  Take a look about the conflicts using column with a singlechildscrollview
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html
Consider using a CustomScrollView
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html